# Same node different template via url

Tags: 7, nodes, theming, uri

I want to use different node templates if the url is appended with ?template=x

Content type is called image

**Default Node template using node--image.tpl.php:**

- blakedesign.co.nz/testsite/node/1

**Same node with different template via URL possibly node--image--templateX.tpl.php:**

- blakedesign.co.nz/testsite/node/1?template=2
- blakedesign.co.nz/testsite/node/1?template=3
- blakedesign.co.nz/testsite/node/1?template=4

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create [custom template suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/223440#custom-suggestions) for node using hook_preprocess_node... In your case it should be below code in your theme template.php file... You can read query arguments using $_GET variable..

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['type'] == "image" && isset($_GET['template'])) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'node__image__template' . $_GET['template'];
  }
}
```

Your template file should be...

```
node--image--template1.tpl.php

node--image--template2.tpl.php

node--image--template3.tpl.php etc...
```

Comment: Works like a charm.
Changed 
`if ($variables['type'] == "image" && $_GET['template']) {`

to

`if ($variables['type'] == "image" && isset($_GET['template'])) {`

Comment: shouldn't it would be better if we use $variables['theme_hook_suggestion'][]